# Wants to move the Azure elastic pool (configured in failover groups) from one subscription to another subscription(different tenant)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-elasticpool, azure-subscription

We have Azure SQL databases in the Azure Elastic pool which are configured in the failover groups. We are planning to move the elastic pool from one subscription to another subscription(to different tenant).

Is it possible to move the elastic pool configured in failover groups to another subscription(different tenant) with out breaking the failover groups.

or else please share the steps/process to perform the activity

Answer (score 1):

Oki so there are two steps, you cannot move resource to a different tenant directly.

What you can do is,

1. Create a temporary subscription in your current tenant, and move these elastic pools into that temporary subscription. see, [Move resources to a new resource group or subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription)

[Can also use Azure resource Mover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-sql)

[Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-sql#prepare-an-elastic-pool): Move Azure SQL Database resources to another region

[image]

2. Then, you can move the temporary subscription to the other tenant. see, [Transfer an Azure subscription to a different Azure AD directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/transfer-subscription)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. What is the need to move the elastic pool into temporary subscription. what about the failover groups? . Moreover those databases are in production.

Comment: In case you have other resources in your current subscription, that you don't want to move to the new tenant, you can move just these sql pool to temp subscription and attach this temp subscription to new tenant

Comment: what a bout the failover groups. when we move the Elastic pool whether failover groups will also move to the new tenant or do we need to break the failover groups  to move the elastic pool.

Comment: Create replica server in destination subscription before move, then fail-over to replica server to move it to destination subscription